# arguments.length run the function if 3 arguments are passed, otherwise throw an error object

Tags: javascript, function, arguments

[Tasks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9e1we.png)I need to modify the displaySortedTaskList function so that it runs if there are 3 arguments passed, and throws an error object with a message if there aren't 3 arguments passed. My attempt:

```
           "use strict";
            var sortTaskList = function(tasks) {
                var isArray = Array.isArray(tasks);
                if (isArray) {
                    tasks.sort();
                }
                return isArray;
            };

            var displaySortedTaskList = function(tasks, div, handler) {
                if(arguments.length = Function.length){

                var html = "";
                var isArray = sortTaskList(tasks);

                        if (isArray) {
                    //create and load html string from sorted array
                    for (var i in tasks) {
                        html = html.concat("<p>");
                        html = html.concat("<a href='#' id='", i, "'>Delete</a>");
                        html = html.concat(tasks[i]);
                        html = html.concat("</p>");
                    }
                    div.innerHTML = html;

                    // get links, loop and add onclick event handler
                    var links = div.getElementsByTagName("a");
                    for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
                        links[i].onclick = handler;
                        } 
                    }
                } else {document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = "The displaySortedTaskList function of the tasklist library requires three arguments"}
            };

            var deleteTask = function(tasks, i) {  
                var isArray = sortTaskList(tasks);
                if (isArray) { tasks.splice(i, 1); }
            };

            var capitalizeTask = function(task) {
                var first = task.substring(0,1);
                return first.toUpperCase() + task.substring(1);
            };
```

Answer (score 0):

You might use rest parameters and check whether the length of the array is 3:

```
var displaySortedTaskList = function(...args) {
  if (args.length !== 3) {
    document.getElementById("message").textContent = "The displaySortedTaskList function of the tasklist library requires three arguments";
    return;
    // or `throw new Error('not enough args')` ?
  }
  const [tasks, div, handler] = args;
  // rest of your code
```

(note that you should assign to `.textContent` when inserting text - `.innerHTML` is appropriate when *inserting HTML markup*, which is not the case here)

Live snippet:

```js
var displaySortedTaskList = function(...args) {
  if (args.length !== 3) {
    return console.log('error');
  }
  console.log('rest of the code');
}

displaySortedTaskList('foo', 'bar');
displaySortedTaskList('foo', 'bar', 'baz');
displaySortedTaskList('foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'buzz');
```

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "isn't working"? What's the error or problem? See live snippet, it looks to have your desired effect

Comment: It just isn't adding the tasks (running the function) or throwing the error message-check the pic I added to my OP. THANK YOU

Comment: If the problem is that the function isn't running in the first place, then that's what you should explain in your question, rather than about how to check logic *inside* the function

Comment: The code you posted doesn't look to call or even reference `displaySortedTaskList` anywhere. If you don't call the function, then the function will never be invoked.

Comment: It is called in another JS file. I am really stumped. I am sorry man

Comment: Why doesn't the last call in the live snippet return error, as it has 4  arguments?

Comment: Oops, comma was inside the string, not outside in the argument list

Comment: ya sorry, I just saw that

Comment: You need to provide a [MCVE] in your question so that the problem you're encountering can be reproduced (so that it can be fixed).